# when is andengine ready for registerEntityModifier calls?

Tags: android, animation, andengine

I'm creating a game using the AndEngine library and I would like some animation to occur on game startup.  Right now, I do this in the onGameResume() method :

```
@Override
public synchronized void onResumeGame() 
{
     super.onResumeGame();
     if (started==false)
     {
         doStartupAnimatons();
         started = true;
     }
}
```

On a powerful device (ex.: Samsung Galaxy S), this runs just fine.  On a lesser device (ex.: Samsung Galaxy mini 2) the animation is already finished when the game appears on screen.

So my question is, when is andengine really ready for executing animations?

Answer (score 0):

how I did startup animations was

1. added a scene changer that calls onAttached() for every scene when attached [I thought it'd do that automatically but apparently it didn't]
2. have each scene that needs an entrance animation override the onAttached() method and do it's animation there

the scene changer should change the current scene first then call onAttached() , that should do it